# Counting items in 2 joined tables in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables:

users:
user_id,
name
...

items:
item_id,
user_id
...

followers:
follower_user_id,
followed_user_id

I want to get info of user + count of his items + count of his followers.
The user might have no items nor followers.

I'm running the following query:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.name, 
    COUNT(items.item_id) AS num_of_items, COUNT(followers.followed_user_id) AS followers 
FROM users
JOIN items
ON users.user_id = items.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN followers
ON users.user_id = followers.followed_user_id
WHERE users.user_id = :user_id
```

But I'm having trouble with the count values.
If one of the count is 0, then the other count turns out right, but if both are not 0, then both will have the same highest value.

For example:

Case 1:
3 items
0 followers
result:
3 items
0 followers

Case 2:
18 items
1 follower
result:
18 items
18 followers

I'd appreciate any help fixing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` for multiple counts in a query that have several joins

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.name, 
    COUNT(distinct items.item_id) AS num_of_items, COUNT(distinct followers.followed_user_id) AS followers 
FROM users
JOIN items
ON users.user_id = items.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN followers
ON users.user_id = followers.followed_user_id
WHERE users.user_id = :user_id
```

Comment: Using DISTINCT did get me closer. I only needed to change "distinct followers.followed_user_id" to "distinct followers.follower_user_id". Thanks!